# How to get bone transform for a particular animation frame

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I have an animation with about 20 frames. I need to be able to access local transforms for each bone for a given animation frame. I know how to access the bone and its local transform (a sample of the code)

```
Transform root, spine1;
getChildFromName(gameObj, "Jnt_Root", out root);
getChildFromName(root, "Jnt_Spine1", out spine1);
spine1.localRotation = someValue;
```

All of this works fine, but I don't know the values I'm getting are from which animation frame? I assume its from frame 1 (can verify using debugger but that's not the point)

The questions is how to get and set these values for a specific frame? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work for getting the current transforms:

```
AnimationState state = animation["your_animation"];
state.enabled = true;
state.normalizedTime = (1.0f/totalAnimationTime) * specificFrame;
animation.Sample();

// get all transforms of this animation, extract your root and spine from here.
Transform[] transforms = animation.gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
```

Or if you're trying to sample while the animation is running you could do something like:

```
if(animation["your_animation"].normalizedTime > 0.3 && animation["your_animation"].normalizedTime < 0.5) {
   //... do something at this point in time.  You'll have to figure out the frame
   //from the time
}
```

Last I checked you can't explicitly extract a particular frame.  But if you know the total length of your animation (time-wise), you can move the animation to that point with something like: `(1.0f/totalAnimationTime) * specificFrame;` (this assumes the keyframes are uniformly spaced.)

Once stored you should be able to modify the transforms directly but I've never tried.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the animation I have is imported along with fbx model and is thus a clip and not a state (or is there something I'm doing wrong?)